# Vagrant password in Debian 11/12

Tags: vagrant

I am using Vagrant to create VMs, but I cannot find the default password for the user **vagrant**.

If there is no password, how can I set it up during provisioning from the Vagrantfile?

Comment: perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450404/is-there-a-default-password-to-connect-to-vagrant-when-using-homestead-ssh-for) will help

Comment: Hmm, not really, as I am looking for the actual passed for the login to the desktop environment

Comment: oh, one of the answers states the default password